# People Search - Show Recent Staff

Tags: user-profile-service

I need to be able to show the latest 5 members of staff to join the organisation on our intranet homepage.  I think the best way to do this would be with the People Search Core Results web part, but I can't come up with a query that will do it.

Can anyone suggest a query to pick out recent staff?  Or pick out all staff, ordered by start date and then limit to 5 only?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you looked at the Anniversary Date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally managed to figure this out:

The main guide is here:
http://www.sharepointsteve.com/2010/10/making-custom-user-profile-properties-searchable-in-sharepoint-2010/

1. Make a custom attribute on user profiles
2. Make that custom attribute import from the whenCreate AD attribute
3. Run an incremental crawl (important, otherwise nothing shows up in step 4!)
4. Add a new Managed Property in search that maps to the custom attribute
5. Edit the People Search Core Results XSL to fetch the Managed Property